# User is always signed in and can't logout in flutter firebase

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

Main Dart:

```dart
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamProvider<MyUser?>.value(
        value: AuthService().user,
        initialData: null,
        child: MaterialApp( //code for material dart
```

Wrapper Widget:

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final user = Provider.of<MyUser?>(context);
    print(user);
    if (user == null) {
      print('no one logged in');
    } else {
      print(user.uid);
    }
    return user == null ? LoginPage() : NavigationBar();
  }
```

So I'm trying to load the login page whenever user is null, but I only logged in the first time and now it stays logged in even after deleting that account from firebase console.

Output after hot restart:

```
Restarted application in 935ms.
flutter: null
flutter: no one logged in
flutter: Instance of 'MyUser'
flutter: ETBVvt2A0JggH8KSrgdLh3DP8cG3
```

I don't get why the first time it returns
'no one logged in' but it runs a second time too and returns the uid of the user that is logged in.

The logout button doesn't work either. It does't return an error or anything, it just doesn't produce any output.

Here is the signOut button method:

```dart
//method
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  Future signOut() async {
    try {
      return await _auth.signOut();
    } catch (error) {
      print(error.toString());
      return null;
    }
```

Signout button:

```dart
 onPressed: () async {
                        dynamic result = await _auth.signOut();
                        if (result == null) {
                          print('error signing out');
                        } else {
                          print('signed out');
                          Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(
                              context, LoginPage.routeName);
                        }
                      },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the problem wasn't with firebase but with the custom button I had built. I didn't assign the onPressed properly and the logout button wasn't working because of that.

Answer (score 1):

Firebase automatically persists the user credentials locally, and tries to restore those when the app is restarted.

To sign the user out, you have to explicitly [sign the user out](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/usage#signing-out) by calling `await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut()`.

Comment: If the method where you call `_auth.signOut()` doesn't produce any output, it seems the user is not being logged out. I recommend stepping through that code in a debugger line by line, and seeing what *does* happen.

Answer (score 0):

**Please call this function in your oppressed area**

`Future<Null> _signOut() async {    await GoogleSignIn().signOut(); print("logout Successfully"); }`

**Here  GoogleSignIn(), is the function where you define your signin codes**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).